# Typescript - Merging two Zod schemas where one is a generic schema, how do I sort out this type error?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics, zod

I am trying to create a function that can add a new property to a generic Zod schema (a standard Zod schema merge), but also produce an item that abides by the newly merged schema. Typescript seems unable to infer that the newly merged item is of the same type as the merged schema.

I need to output both the merged object and the merged schema as a Zod run-time typecheck will be done later down the line.

##### Inputs and outputs laid out:

- Input: takes in a generic Zod schema and an object that abides by that schema (`originalSchema` and `item`).
- Process: adds a property to the schema (in this case `version: z.number()`). It also adds the property/value to the object (`version: 1`)
- Output: The merged schema, and an item that abides by the merged schema (`mergedSchema` and `itemWithVersioning`)

##### Minimal code demonstrating the issue:

```
import { z } from "zod";

// Generic schema for versioned items
const versioningSchema = z.object({
  version: z.number(),
});

export const addVersioningToItem = <U extends z.ZodRawShape>(
  originalSchema: z.ZodObject<U>,
  item: z.infer<z.ZodObject<U>>,
) => {

  const mergedSchema = originalSchema.merge(versioningSchema);

  type combinedSchema = z.infer<typeof mergedSchema>;

  // This type errors:
  const itemWithVersioning: combinedSchema = {
    ...item,
    version: 1,
  }

  // This function MUST return a value of type combinedSchema, as 'mergedSchema' will be used later to validate the item
  return {mergedSchema, itemWithVersioning};
};
```

The line

```
const itemWithVersioning: combinedSchema = {
```

Is erroring, saying `itemWithVersioning` does not abide by combinedSchema.

##### Resulting Error

The type error for `const itemWithVersioning: combinedSchema` is as follows:

```
Type '{ [k in keyof addQuestionMarks<baseObjectOutputType<U>, requiredKeys<baseObjectOutputType<U>>>]: addQuestionMarks<...>[k]; } & { ...; }' is not assignable to type '{ [k in keyof addQuestionMarks<baseObjectOutputType<{ [k in keyof (Omit<U, "version"> & { version: ZodNumber; })]: (Omit<U, "version"> & { version: ZodNumber; })[k]; }>, requiredKeys<...>>]: addQuestionMarks<...>[k]; }'.
```

Pretty difficult to interpret...

---

I appreciate I could use `as` in this toy example, I wish to not use it in our sofware... hence this stack overflow question.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I also tried making `originalSchema` non-generic. This worked, however the function's point is to add versioning to many different schemas so it must be generic. This does tell me though that it's to-do with the generic nature of the input.

Comment: Would it be enough to use the `and` method? You get a less useful `ZodIntersection` object that lacks some methods but still works.